# I can not able to receive the push notification from server through GCM?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am new to GCM Push notification. I can able to get the Registration ID. I have send that Registration ID and API key to the server. But From Server side if they send Push means I can't able to receive that. Can You please any one help?

Comment: any error will come have u Registration Id

Comment: no i did not get any error

Comment: have u create any web page for sending push notification

Comment: yeah We have created

Comment: check using echo what error is getting or sending message to device

Comment: that means error is from server side ?

Comment: Can you share your code of receiver and generating push key?

Answer (score 3):

Please check the server key in google console and your server side.

Or see the following link :

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start.

Make sure about the use of the key for sending GCM.

Answer (score 0):

Write GCM BroadCastReaceiver and GCM intent service in your APP ..

At server side use that stored GCM ids to send notification...

```
<?php

function sendNotifications($con,$message) {

    // Get list of ids to send to
    $gcmRegID = getRegistrationIDs($con, null, null, null,null, null);
    //Post message to GCM when submitted
    $pushStatus = "GCM Status Message will appear here";
        if (isset($gcmRegID)) {     
            $gcmRegIds = $gcmRegID;//this is registered GCM id 
            $message = array("sc_description" => $description); 
            $message['sc_title']=$title;
            $message['sc_type']=$type;
            $message['sc_id']=$message_id;
            $pushStatus = sendMessageThroughGCM($gcmRegIds, $message);
            return $pushStatus;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I already write the GCM Intent Service in my app even though i did not get. I have to write any code for receiving the notification in onMessage override method in GCM Intent Service ?

Comment: then check Google Cloud Messaging API Key is correct and ur getting the GCM id correctly try to print while debugging and at server side echo the data ur sending.